# Many threads to write log file at same time in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, python-2.x

I am writing a script to retrieve WMI info from many computers at the same time then write this info in a text file:

```
f = open("results.txt", 'w+') ## to clean the results file before the start


def filesize(asset):  
    f = open("results.txt", 'a+')  
    c = wmi.WMI(asset)  
    wql = 'SELECT FileSize,Name FROM CIM_DataFile where (Drive="D:" OR Drive="E:") and Caption like "%file%"'  
    for item in c.query(wql):  
        print >> f, item.Name.split("\\")[2].strip().upper(), str(item.FileSize)  




class myThread (threading.Thread):  
    def __init__(self,name):  
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)  
        self.name = name  
    def run(self):  
        pythoncom.CoInitialize ()  
        print "Starting " + self.name       
        filesize(self.name)  
        print "Exiting " + self.name  



thread1 = myThread('10.24.2.31')  
thread2 = myThread('10.24.2.32')  
thread3 = myThread('10.24.2.33')  
thread4 = myThread('10.24.2.34')  
thread1.start()  
thread2.start()  
thread3.start()  
thread4.start()
```

The problem is that all threads writing at the same time.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can simply create your own locking mechanism to ensure that only one thread is ever writing to a file.

```
import threading
lock = threading.Lock()

def write_to_file(f, text, file_size):
    lock.acquire() # thread blocks at this line until it can obtain lock

    # in this section, only one thread can be present at a time.
    print >> f, text, file_size

    lock.release()

def filesize(asset):  
    f = open("results.txt", 'a+')  
    c = wmi.WMI(asset)  
    wql = 'SELECT FileSize,Name FROM CIM_DataFile where (Drive="D:" OR Drive="E:") and Caption like "%file%"'  
    for item in c.query(wql):  
        write_to_file(f, item.Name.split("\\")[2].strip().upper(), str(item.FileSize))
```

You may want to consider placing the lock around the entire for loop `for item in c.query(wql):` to allow each thread to do a larger chunk of work before releasing the lock.

Comment: If a thread tries to write_to_file while the file is locked to another thread, will both still get their turn to write?

Comment: Yes when the thread that has the lock releases it, the waiting thread will obtain the lock.

Comment: @MartinKonecny I am using this acquire and release method for a python script where 4 threads write to one file simultaneously. It neatly aligns the tasks and prevents writing errors. I am working on a second (completely separate script) that is writing to the same file as the first. When running at the same time, does the lock and acquire method implemented in the first script also prevent simultaneous access by the second script (where it isn't implemented)? I.e Does this method lock the file for every script attempting to access it at that time? ...curious but the documentation is unclear.

Comment: Nope, this lock method will only work for threads running in the same script

Comment: why some people use `with lock : #operation`

Answer (score 7):

`print` is not thread safe. Use the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module instead (which is):

```
import logging
import threading
import time


FORMAT = '[%(levelname)s] (%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format=FORMAT)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler('results.log')
file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(FORMAT))
logging.getLogger().addHandler(file_handler)


def worker():
    logging.info('Starting')
    time.sleep(2)
    logging.info('Exiting')


t1 = threading.Thread(target=worker)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=worker)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Output (and contents of `results.log`):

```
[INFO] (Thread-1  ) Starting
[INFO] (Thread-2  ) Starting
[INFO] (Thread-1  ) Exiting
[INFO] (Thread-2  ) Exiting
```

Instead of using the default name (`Thread-n`), you can set your own name using the `name` keyword argument, which the `%(threadName)` formatting directive then will then use:

```
t = threading.Thread(name="My worker thread", target=worker)
```

---

(This example was adapted from an example from [Doug Hellmann's excellent article about the `threading` module](http://pymotw.com/2/threading/))

Answer (score 3):

For another solution, use a `Pool` to calculate data, returning it to the parent process. This parent then writes all data to a file. Since there's only one proc writing to the file at a time, there's no need for additional locking.

Note the following uses a pool of *processes*, not *threads*. This makes the code much simpler and easier than putting something together using the `threading` module. (There is a `ThreadPool` object, but it's not documented.)

### source

```
import glob, os, time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def filesize(path):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return (path, os.path.getsize(path))

paths = glob.glob('*.py')
pool = Pool()                   # default: proc per CPU

with open("results.txt", 'w+') as dataf:
    for (apath, asize) in pool.imap_unordered(
            filesize, paths,
    ):
        print >>dataf, apath,asize
```

### output in results.txt

```
zwrap.py 122
usercustomize.py 38
tpending.py 2345
msimple4.py 385
parse2.py 499
```