# save multi thread output to txt file

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, save, python-multithreading

i write this simple code ... i need to save the code output to text file in my pc how i can do that ?

```
import threading
import time


def qan(hey):
    while True:

        d = hey + 1
        print d
        time.sleep(1)


def printd(printme):
    while True:
        print printme + "\n"
        time.sleep(1)


t1 = threading.Thread(target=qan, args=(1,))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=printd, args=("hey",))
t2.start()
t1.start()
```

and this is my code output

> hey
>
> 2 2  hey
>
> 2hey
>
> 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [many threads to write log file at same time python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26325943/many-threads-to-write-log-file-at-same-time-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some buffer with data:

```
import threading
import time


buffer = []

def qan(hey):
    while True:

        d = hey + 1
        buffer.append(d)
        time.sleep(1)


def printd(printme):
    while True:
        buffer.append(printme + "\n")
        time.sleep(1)


t1 = threading.Thread(target=qan, args=(1,))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=printd, args=("hey",))
t2.start()
t1.start()

with open('output.txt') as f:
    f.write(''.join(buffer))
```

Comment: its now working u got an error after i modify the code :
with open('output.txt' , "a") as f:

    f.write('\n'.join(str(buffer)) )

Comment: output : ['hey\n', 2] just oneline !!

Comment: rewrite first buffer.append as buffer.append(str(d) + '\n')

Comment: First of all, print in python prints string with '\n' , and join method works only with list strings